# Convert Rails record dates to human readable date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In javascript, I want to convert a standard date format given by Rails into something human readable.

Rails uses this for its records:
`2014-06-17T19:48:42.072Z`

Given that string in javascript, what is the easiest to get it into something where we can work with it? Ideally formatting it as `June 17, 2014`?

Assume you cannot transform the date with Rails before giving it to javascript.

Comment: Maybe I've been coding too long and have started to turn into a robot, but I think the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format is actually more readable, less ambiguous, and not subject to regional/national reading preferences when compared to these so-called "human" formats. May the machines be benevolent rulers of us someday. ;)

Comment: Haha, I appreciate that but for our non-coder brethren that date string contains way too much information for what they care about :P

Answer (score 0):

37signals has a pretty cool [rails engine/javascript plugin](https://github.com/basecamp/local_time) to display UTC times in a user's local time.

From their example:

```
> comment.created_at
"Wed, 27 Nov 2013 18:43:22 EST -0500"

<%= local_time(comment.created_at) %>
```

Renders:

```
<time data-format="%B %e, %Y %l:%M%P"
      data-local="time"
      datetime="2013-11-27T23:43:22Z">November 27, 2013 11:43pm</time>
```

When the DOM loads, the content is immediately replaced with a local, formatted time:

```
<time data-format="%B %e, %Y %l:%M%P"
      data-local="time"
      datetime="2013-11-27T23:43:22Z"
      title="November 27, 2013 6:43pm EDT"
      data-localized="true">November 27, 2013 6:43pm</time>
```